# How to setup cx_oracle in Solaris?

Tags: python, solaris

Need information on how to install the  Python 3.4 x64 on Solaris x64.

I can not find good information.

Answer (score 2):

On Solaris 11.3, simply `pkg install cx_oracle` as described in https://blogs.oracle.com/jmcp/entry/cx_oracle_v5_2_for.  If you need the module specifically for Python 3.4, it would be `pkg install cx_oracle-34`.

Comment: I made a mistake.
The problem lies in the compilation Python 3.4 x64 for Solaris x64.

Comment: Python 3.4 x64 is also a simple pkg install on Solaris 11.3.  If you need to build it yourself for an older version, you'll need to provide more info than "problem lies in the compilation".