# Install cx_oracle on solaris 11 sparc

Tags: python, python-2.7, solaris, cx-oracle

Most of the cx_Oracle 5.2.1 version builds are for Windows and Linux. How do I install/get an install for a Solaris 11 Sparc?

I tried to install using the following: cx_Oracle-5.2.1.tar.gz from sourceforge.net
But resulted in the following error:

```
/tmp/cx_Oracle-5.2.1$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'cx_Oracle' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7-11g
cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC -I/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/rdbms/demo -I/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1/rdbms/public -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c cx_Oracle.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7-11g/cx_Oracle.o -DBUILD_VERSION=5.2.1
unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Please advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup cx\_oracle in Solaris?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779349/how-to-setup-cx-oracle-in-solaris)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle (nor Sun, for that matter) did not include a compiler in the Solaris OS installation image.  The Solaris Studio compiler is available for download, and of course you can also go the GCC route (UNIX Packages web site offers installable packages of GCC and various libraries needed for dependences for a modest fee.)

The original post is quote old though, and the solution as of now is to simply install the cx_oracle package from the 11.3 or 11.4 IPS.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact reason for the error you are getting. It looks, however, like the "cc" compiler is not installed. You should be able to find that package and install it. Or you will need to adjust your configuration to use gcc instead. This link may help:

http://www.unix.com/solaris/114262-command-cc-failed-even-though-gcc-installed.html