# Compiler problem installing cx_Oracle using pip on Solaris

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, solaris, cx-oracle

I'm new to this stuff and any help would be awesome. I'm installing this through putty on an onprem server.

```
Collecting cx_Oracle==7.3

  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/e3/cfd4f413f8d47dd2aee09273d9bb3ee6aa7384e0a04e191d703c2199eb93/cx_Oracle-7.3.0.tar.gz (307kB)

    100% |################################| 317kB 7.6MB/s

Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle

  Running setup.py install for cx-Oracle ... error

    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-YAwTvN/cx-Oracle/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-nqdlEI/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:

    running install

    running build

    running build_ext

    building 'cx_Oracle' extension

    creating build

    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7

    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7/src

    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7/odpi

    creating build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7/odpi/src

    cc -DNDEBUG -KPIC -DPIC -DCXO_BUILD_VERSION=7.3.0 -Iodpi/include -Iodpi/src -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cxoBuffer.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-sun4v.32bit-2.7/src/cxoBuffer.o

    unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory

    error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

 

    ----------------------------------------

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-YAwTvN/cx-Oracle/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-nqdlEI/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-YAwTvN/cx-Oracle/
```

Previously I was able to install awscli without any issues.
I'm not sure why is this happening.

Comment: `unable to execute 'cc': No such file or directory` means the compiler wasn't found in `PATH`. Find out where the compiler resides on your system and append its parent directory to `PATH`, then retry the `pip install ...` command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, and sorry if my question is naive. how can I get the location of the compiler? The server is a Unix based Solaris server. and what exactly do you mean by `PATH` . Also, I ahve noticed this error pop up for many libraries I have tried to install: `Running setup.py install for cx-Oracle ... error`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966698/install-cx-oracle-on-solaris-11-sparc